# Hibernate JPA : ignore wrong sql foreign key values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, myisam

I have a project to maintain, The persistance layer of this project uses `JPA` and `Hibernate` and it is running on a `MySQL` server, the database is not  `relational` and the engine is `MyISAM` on all tables.

I have some foreignkey relationshps mapped as `@ManyToOne` relationship on my entities.

Now the problem is that some of those columns are supposed to be `foreignkeys` in order to be mapped right, but they aren't (since the engine is `MyISAM`, and the `DB` is only `relational` on theory), some of these columns have wrong values like **(negative ones -1 , 0 , inexistant dead parents)**.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="COL_FK")
   private EntityB b;

}
```

In the DB, Possible values for `COL_FK` are : `0,-1,DEAD PARENTS`

I can't neither change the db structure nor edit the 
the data within the columns.All I can do is change the code.

How can I tell Hibernate to ignore those values and not throw a `RuntimeException` while I'm getting list just because one of its element contains a wrong `foreingkey` value.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityA {
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "idClient")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private ClientBO idClient;

}
```

StackTrace :

```
AVERTISSEMENT: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find xx.xxx.xx.xxx.ClientBO with id 210; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find xx.xx.xx.xxx.ClientBO with id 210
```

Comment: add a try catch where it's throwing the `RuntimeException` but that sounds pretty squirrely to me, since anytime after that if the foreign object is referenced you'll most likely encounter a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @j.con that's not an option, It is not a problem with oneElement, it is a whole table problem, for example when you try to get a list of element you will get the exception and the whole list won't load since one element can't be mapped.

Comment: are you using `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery` when you are grabbing the table data?

Comment: @j.con I am using `Spring-data-jpa` with `querydsl` and sometimes `Specification`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Annotate your association with

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

Note that this is one more hack on top of an already ugly solution though. Hibernate heavily relies on transactions (as it should) and MyISAM, AFAIK, doesn't support transactions. I guess you already knows it, but fixing the database would be a much better choice.

Comment: yes I know , the problem is that the solution is already ugly,and  I have `Permission Denied` to change it. All i can do is trying to fix the code. the hack didn't work though I'm keep getting `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`

Comment: That is supposed to work. You should edit your question, post your updated entity code, the code of a minimal test case reproducing the problem, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why I had a strange behaviour when i tested it on the first time and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=InnoDB.

MyISAM accepts the syntax for `FOREIGN KEYs`, but does not implement them.  It also ignores any commands (like `COMMIT`) relating to transactions.

MyISAM *does* handle "relations".  It handles `INDEXes` and `JOINs`.  It just doesn't do the extra stuff that `FOREIGN KEYs` provide.